# adding seconds to a datetime variable in node.js

Tags: node.js, datetime

I have following code:

```
var dbDate = '2013-11-15 12:51:18';
var seconds = 30;
```

I want to get date after adding the seconds in the same format. Like:

```
var resultDate = dbDate + seconds; //'2013-11-15 12:51:48'
```

How to get desired result?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var dbDate = '2013-11-15 12:51:18';
var seconds = 30;


var parsedDate = new Date(Date.parse(dbDate))
var newDate = new Date(parsedDate.getTime() + (1000 * seconds))


console.log(formatDate(newDate))


function formatDate(date){
    return ('{0}-{1}-{3} {4}:{5}:{6}').replace('{0}', date.getFullYear()).replace('{1}', date.getMonth() + 1).replace('{3}', date.getDate()).replace('{4}', date.getHours()).replace('{5}', date.getMinutes()).replace('{6}', date.getSeconds())
}
```

Comment: Agreed answer. No need for another library simply to add seconds.

Comment: fix your answer from `date.getDay()` to `date.getDate()`

Answer (score 3):

I would make use of the [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/) library for this. You could then achieve what you want as follows:

```
var moment = require('moment');

var dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';

var dbDate = '2013-11-15 12:51:18';
var seconds = 30;
var resultDate = moment(dbDate).add('seconds', seconds).format(dateFormat);
```

This makes use of the `moment` [`#add()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and [`#format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
var a;
/// create our date from our nicely formatted Y-m-d H:i:s string
a = new Date('2013-11-15 12:51:18');
/// add 30 seconds
a = new Date(a.getTime() + (30 * 1000));
/// use toISOString, it's the closest to Y-m-d H:i:s
a = a.toISOString();
/// modify ISO string to get Y-m-d H:i:s
a = a.split('.')[0].replace('T', ' ');
/// output!
console.log( a );
```