# How can we convert a time to given format with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a lot of second values like `12.5` and I want to format it like`00:00:12,500`

Is it possible to do this with MomentJS ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945410/adding-seconds-to-a-datetime-variable-in-node-js/20945982 this might help

Comment: @oconnecp Thanks I know how to do this but I should do it by using MomentJS

Comment: both answers were in that stack overflow question.  If you don't need a library, use the function I wrote, if you have MomentJS already, the answer for how to implement it is in a different answer.  Personally, I skip the momentJS library

Comment: I asked how to do it with MomentJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way:

```
const durationInSeconds = 12.5;
const formattedDuration = moment.utc( 
  moment.duration(durationInSeconds, 'seconds').asMilliseconds() 
).format('HH:mm:ss,SSS');

// 00:00:12,500
```

Comment: Thanks for answering